# How to implement search in jQgrid so that user can filter by <,> or <=, >=?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

The jQuery grid has filter options on top, where I can either enter "text" or implement a dropdown list.

What I wish to do however, is allow the use to search an int column such as "tax" with configurable options such as '<10' where both '<' and '10' should be user parameters. This would be a sort of customer search.

I prefer not to have this search in an additional modal, but as a last resort that is also ok.

Here is what I have so far.

```js
var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
        {id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"blah",note:"stuff",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        
    ];
grid = jQuery("#list"); 

grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
           {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", search: true},
           {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
           {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
           {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number"},
           {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float",
          searchoptions: {sopt:['gt']}
            },        
           {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}        
       ],
       pager: "#pager",
       viewrecords: true,
       autowidth: true,
       height: 'auto',
       caption: "Test Grid"
});

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.2/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you need, you should add `searchOperators: true` to the options of `filterToolbar` and to specify more as one compare operation in `sopt` property of `searchoptions`. For example,

```
{name: "tax", width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float",
   searchoptions: {
     sopt: ["le", "lt", "gt", "ge", "eq", "ne"]
   }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/z6rfw3cp/